# Starcraft II ending transcript

Tags: starcraft-2

May someone give me a transcript of cinematic ending of Starcraft II HOTS. I am not native, so it's difficult for me to understand that all.

I just heard

> "**I now see my true enemy...**"

Comment: To answerers: spoiler tags, please.

Comment: I cannot up vote that comment enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the Subtitle in the cinematic, as [iber pointed out in his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108848/12936) in the Options menu.

---

***Now the transcriptions. (forgive-me if I made some mistakes, not my primary language)***

### Starcraft 2 Wings of Liberty

> 0:39 Sarah. 
>  0:50 You're reading all this? 
>  0:52 You have your orders, Mister Findlay. Carry them out. 
>  1:03 Tychus. What have you done? 
>  1:10 I made a deal with the devil, Jimmy. She dies I go free. 
>  1:20 We all got our choices to make. 
>  1:28 Damn shame. 
>  1:34 pew **pew** pew **pew**... 
>  1:41 Jim? 
>  1:43 It's ok. I got you. 
>  1:51 ~Song that I don't know the name, but it's cute, romantic and a little sad.~

[Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8xG8ykoK4E)

### Starcraft 2 - Heart of the Swarm

> 1:06 Hello Kerrigan. I've being waiting for you. 
>  1:11 I'm surprised you haven't try to escape. 
>  1:14 Escape? My dear, I'm afraid you got all wrong. 
>  1:40 Really? Did you think I keep an animal like you close to me, without some kind of insurance policy? 
>  1:56 Clearly, you're my greatest failure. Now, at long last You Will DIE. 
>  2:13 Change of plans! 
>  2:31 You can never suffer enough for all the lives that you ruined, Arcturus. 
>  2:40 I made you into a monster Kerrigan 
>  2:46 You made us all into monsters 
>  3:34 Thank you Jim 
>  3:40 For everything 
>  3:48 My pleasure darling 
>  3:56 Always was 
>  4:20 I now see my true enemy.  
>  4:25 He waits for me in the void.  
>  4:28 Wielding powers I can only imagine. 
>  4:32 I go to face him, having renounced everything. 
>  4:37 My humanity. 
>  4:40 My identity. 
>  4:42 The man I love. 
>  4:45 But I'll not face this enemy alone. 
>  4:50 **I'm the SWARM!**

[Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kScAk4L7Y3Q)

PS: I wrote the WoL too because I watched it first and only when I finished the transcription I noticed that it was not the HotS =X

PS2: As pointed out by [iber](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108848/12936) you can do it in-game, without too much trouble.

> "**Menu > Options > Gameplay.** It is under the right column of choices".

Comment: A little help at 2:31 would be appreciated. I couldn't understand the last piece of the text.

Comment: 2:31 says You can never suffer enough for all the lives that you ruined, Arcturus. (Arcturus is his first name.)

Comment: Pew pew pew pew!

Answer (score 13):

I can't help you directly. Still you can turn on subtitles and watch ending again.

**Menu > Options > Gameplay**. It is under the right column of choices.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: +1 I think this is much better than posting the transcript and spoiling the game ending for some people.